# Linux -Can I rsync to dropbox or another free cloud storage service?

Tags: linux, backup, cloud-storage, dropbox

We host a small community, not for profit site and mailing list, is it possible to rsync to dropbox or a similar (free) service to maintain backup?

Edit: For context, we host on a shared VM and don't want to install anything unless we have to. I'm currently looking at [dropbox-uploader](http://www.howopensource.com/2014/09/simple-linux-backup-to-dropbox/) which is just a bash script

Thanks

Comment: Just install Dropbox. You've installed other things. It's a tiny footprint. Question the question here rather than provide a non-answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Box has ftp (https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/200520128-Using-Box-with-FTP).

AFAIK Dropbox only have http for download purposes

EDIT: By the way, you cannot use rsync with ftp but you can mount ftp as a local mount and use rsync with that folder.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, quite easily. Setup the dropbox folder outside the hierarchy that you will be backing up (for instance, if you are backing up /export/home, setup your dropbox folder as /opt/dropbox), and then setup your job to do a local-to-local rsync.

Hope that helps.

Happy Monday.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I feel my question is wrong. I should have been more specific. Is there a way I can script this rather than install the dropbox software? We host on a shared VM (kindly donated) and don't want to install things on the server unless we have to

Comment: If you are asking whether you can use rsync to natively sync to dropbox, then no. However you can rsync (probably over SSH) to another box that has the dropbox agent running.